# DDD considering Repositories & Services for entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

I've been getting acquainted with `DDD` and trying to understand the way `Entities` and `Aggregate Roots` interact.

**Below is the example of the situation:**

Let's say there is a user and he/she has multiple email addresses (can have up to 200 for the sake of example). Each email address has it's own identity and so does the user. And there is `one to many` relationship between users and their email.

---

From the above example I consider `Users` and `Emails` as two entities while `Users` is the `aggregate root`

DDD Rules that I came across:

- **Rule:** Only `aggregate root` has access to the repository.

**Question 1:** Does it mean that I cannot have a separate database table/collection to store the emails separately? Meaning that the emails have to be embedded inside the user document.

- **Rule:** `Entities` outside the `aggregate` can only access other `entities` in the `aggregate` via the `aggregate root`.

**Question 2:** Now considering I do split them up into two different tables/collection and link the emails by having a field in email called `associatedUserId` that holds the reference to the user that email belongs to. I can't directly have an API endpoint like `/users/{userId}/emails` and handle it directly in the `EmailService.getEmailsByUserId(String userId)`? If not how do I model this?

I am sorry if the question seems a bit too naive but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Only aggregate root has access to the repository*
>
> Does it mean that I cannot have a separate database table/collection to store the emails separately? Meaning that the emails have to be embedded inside the user document.

It means that there should be a single lock to acquire if you are going to make any changes to any of the member entities of the aggregate.  That certainly means that the data representation of the aggregate is stored in a single database; but you could of course distribute the information across multiple tables in that database.

Back in 2003, using relational databases as the book of record was common; one to many relationships would normally involve multiple tables all within the same database.

> *Entities outside the aggregate can only access other entities in the aggregate via the aggregate root.*
>
> I can't directly have an API endpoint like /users/{userId}/emails and handle it directly in the EmailService.getEmailsByUserId(String userId)?

Of course you can; you'll do that by first loading the root entity of the User aggregate, then invoking methods on that entity to get at the information that you need.

A perspective: Evans was taking a position against the idea that the application should be able to manipulate *arbitrary* entities in the domain model directly.  Instead, the application should only be allowed to the "root" entities in the domain model.  The restriction, in effect, means that the application doesn't really need to understand the constraints that are shared by multiple entities.

Four or five years later [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) appeared, further refining this idea -- it turns out that in read-only use cases, the domain model doesn't necessarily contribute very much; you don't need to worry about the invariants if they have already been satisfied and you aren't changing anything.

In effect, this suggests that `GET /users/{userId}/emails` can just pull the data out of a read-only view, without necessarily involving the domain model at all.  But `POST /users/{userId}/emails` needs to demonstrate the original care (meaning, we need to modify the data via the domain model)

> does this mean that I need to first go to the UserRepo and pull out the user and then pull out the emails, can't I just make a EmailService talking to an Email Repo directly

In the original text by Evans, repositories give access to *root entities*, rather than arbitrary entities.  So if "email" is a an entity within the "user aggregate", then it normally wouldn't have a repository of its own.

Furthermore, if you find yourself fighting against that idea, it may be a "code smell" trying to bring you to recognize that your aggregate boundaries are in the wrong place.  If email and user are in different aggregates, then of *course* you would use different repositories to get at them.

The trick is to recognize that aggregate design is a reflection of how we lock our data for modification, not how we link our data for reporting.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, so talking about the point 2, you mentioned _"you'll do that by first loading the root entity of the User aggregate"_ does this mean that I need to first go to the UserRepo and pull out the user and then pull out the emails, can't I just make a EmailService talking to an Email Repo directly (`query like Select * from emails where user = some@email.com`). From the later part of your answer I think I can do that but I am just confirming. Also can you please elaborate on the last words _"demonstrate the original care"_

Comment: See the revisions to the answer

Comment: Can we move this to a quick chat window? Because I not able to wrap this around me head for some reason because the email entity although is just an arbitrary entity under the aggregate of the user but it does have it's own Id and a life-cycle and a way of interacting with other entities. Does this mean that email is likely an aggregate on it's own? maybe but reason why I put them under the same aggregate was because it doesn't make sense to have an email without a user.